# Date update in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to change the value of the date field at the time of a data edit. I can bring all the values ​​except the date.

I'm using the **Form::** *Laravel*:

```
{!! Form::label('dtemissao','Data de Emissão') !!}
{!! Form::input('date','dtemissao',$FinContaspagar[0]["DtEmissao"]->format("d/m/Y"), ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}<br />
```

I'm using the `$FinContaspagar[0]["DtEmissao"]->format("d/m/Y")` to change the default value of **dd/mm/yyyy**, but I was not successful in changing the value. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: But if you don't use the `->format("d/m/Y")`?

Comment: I got it using `$FinContaspagar[0]["DtEmissao"]->format('Y-m-d')`. Tks!

Comment: Laravel already updates the timestamps when it is touched, you should have a "updated_at and "created_at fields in your db. which negates the need for this input